# Create tar file in ssh

Tags: ssh, tar

I would like to tar a folder into a file. This file should not be saved on the local machine but on another which can be reached via ssh.

Can I do something like that?

```
tar cfv ssh://user:pass@server:/tmp/myfile.tar myfolder/
```

Answer (score 7):

Without the need of a temporary file:

```
tar cfv - myfolder/ | ssh user@server 'cat > /tmp/myfile.tar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to do this the easy way. This might be a very simplistic approach, but it gets the job done.

```
tar cfv myfile.tar myfolder/ && scp myfile.tar user:pass@server:/tmp/myfile.tar && rm myfile.tar
```

(did not test this, forgive me in case it has an error)